# System settings and software center disapeared

Tags: software-center, settings, system

This is my 1st time to try a linux desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 with a hope to have a stable and usable version of linux.
It worked well at the beginning with some popular applications at the first day.

However, for unknown reason, (maybe after installing Dropbox or after a system update), the software center was disappeared and all software installed via software center were gone together.

System Settings cannnot be launched. Then I tried this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

So system settings can be opened again but most items in system setting are not displaying.
There are only 4 items there including Printer, Security and Privacy, Language, and Software & Update. All others are not there.

When I click About this computer, instead of displaying computer info, it displays System Settings now.

So what's going on with this? It's so frustrated.

BTW, I am an experienced Windows user and couldn't understand why the core components are disappeared in Ubuntu. Can you image that Control Panel is disappeared in Windows? In Windows, I can try system restore or safe mode. It seems I don't have options to try in Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Open system settings and click on all settings at the top left of the window, did that help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstall them by entering in tty2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and that might work fine.

Comment: Hey Michael, this is a new user, am not sure he knows what tty2 is, leave alone how to enter into it.